# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter' in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, parameters, casting

I am trying to call a stored procedure in a C# project that returns 2 values in addition to some input parameters in Oracle 11g.
The procedure is a simple login that returns a varchar2 ('T' or 'F') (*oracle does not accept booleans?*) if there is a user stored that matches the username and password, and it should return a number (1 or 2) for the type of user that it is.

If I test the procedure **with just** the '**pexito**'(success) output parameter it works, but it doesn't with the '**ptipo**'(type of user)) parameter.

I tried changing the datatype of the 'ptipo' parameter to varchar2 and string in the c# code , parsing in different ways, converting to string and then to int and lots of other things. Nothing works, same error always.

*"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter'"*

Here is the PL/SQL SP code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_login
(puser IN VARCHAR2, ppass IN VARCHAR2,  pexito OUT VARCHAR2, ptipo OUT NUMBER )
AS
lfila NUMBER;
ltipo number;
BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO lfila
FROM usuario
WHERE user_login = puser AND pass_login = ppass;

SELECT idtipo_user
INTO ltipo
FROM usuario
WHERE user_login = puser AND pass_login = ppass;

IF lfila = 0 THEN pexito:='F';
ELSE pexito:='T';
END IF;

IF ltipo =NULL THEN ptipo:=NULL;
ELSE ptipo:=ltipo;
END IF;


END;
/
```

And here is the C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
//using System.Data.OracleClient; DEPRECATED
using Sistema_On_Tour.Vistas;
using Sistema_On_Tour.Controlador;

    private void BtnIniciar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Conexion.conn);

                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("sp_login", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    OracleParameter paruser = new OracleParameter("puser", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                    paruser.Value= TxtUser.Text;
                    paruser.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paruser);


                    OracleParameter parpass = new OracleParameter("ppass", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                    parpass.Value = TxtPass.Text;
                    parpass.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parpass);

                    OracleParameter parexito = new OracleParameter("pexito", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                    parexito.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    parexito.Size = 1; 
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parexito);

                    OracleParameter ptipo = new OracleParameter("ptipo", OracleDbType.Int32);
                    ptipo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    ptipo.Size = 1; 
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("ptipo");

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    string exito = cmd.Parameters["pexito"].Value.ToString();
                    int tipouser = int.Parse(cmd.Parameters["ptipo"].Value.ToString());

                    if (exito.Equals('T'))
                    {
                        if (tipouser == 1)
                        {
                            this.Hide();
                            VentanaPrincipalApoderado v = new VentanaPrincipalApoderado();
                            v.Show();
                        }
                        else if(tipouser==2)
                        {
                            this.Hide();
                            VentanaPrincipalEjecutivo v = new VentanaPrincipalEjecutivo();
                            v.Show();
                        }
                    }


                    MessageBox.Show(exito);
                }
                catch(Exception error)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(error.Message);

                }
                finally
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, `OracleDbType` does not support Boolean, use `1/0` or `T/F` as you did. Two minor issues: `IF ltipo = NULL` is **never** TRUE, use `IF ltipo IS NULL` instead. I think `tipouser  = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["ptipo"].Value)`  is more reliable (not for int, but in general)

Comment: Thank you! That helped me too in someway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with Line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("ptipo");
```

Instead you have to do

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add(ptipo);
```

Note : You have  to pass Variable not name of the variable as a string.

Comment: Oh my god I can't believe I missed that Add statement! Thanks so much! I spent like 3 hours trying to resolve that issue

Answer (score 0):

This Kind of thing will not work

```
OracleParameter paruser = new OracleParameter("puser", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
                    paruser.Value= TxtUser.Text;
                    paruser.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(paruser);
```

Do just like below code other wise you will get conversion error.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_UserName", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = login.UserName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_UPassword", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = login.Password;
cmd.Parameters.Add("cur_splogin", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```